# Как сделать маску для ввода даты рождения в picker vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, mask

Есть пикер, который отвечает за дату рождения, то есть можно выбрать дату с календаря:

`<el-date-picker id="date_birth" type="date" placeholder="Дата" v-model="user.date_birth"></el-date-picker>`

Нужно сделать также ввод и с клавиатуры по маске, чтобы черточки сами появлялись YYYY-MM-DD. Как можно это сделать, подскажите, люди добрые ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для маскирования значения в `el-date-picker` используется аттрибут `format`.

Пример:

```
<el-date-picker format="YYYY/MM/DD"/>
```